# group nested dictionary by key value

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by

How can I group a nested dictionary by a key value?
For example, my dictionary looks like this:

```
{'comb_indx': {0: '3925220EE', 1: '3925220EE', 2: '3925220EE', 3: '66478EE', 4: '66478EE', 5: '66478EE', 6: '42300EE', 7: '42300EE', 8: '42300EE'}, country': {0: 'EE', 1: 'EE', 2: ''EE', 3: 'EE', 4: 'EE', 5: 'EE', 6: 'EE', 7: 'EE', 8: 'EE'}, 'type': {0: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 1: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 2: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 3: 'SMALL_LOAN', 4: 'SMALL_LOAN', 5: 'SMALL_LOAN', 6: 'SMALL_LOAN', 7: 'SMALL_LOAN', 8: 'SMALL_LOAN'}}
```

I would like to convert this dictionary into smth like this: Basically, group by values in 'comb_indx':

```
{
{ 'comb_indx': 3925220EE, 'country': {0: 'EE', 1: 'EE', 2: ''EE'}, 'type': {0: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 1: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 2: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT'}}, 
{ 'comb_indx': 66478EE, 'country': {3: 'EE', 4: 'EE', 5: ''EE'}, 'type': {3: 'SMALL_LOAN', 4: 'SMALL_LOAN', 5: 'SMALL_LOAN'}}, 
{ 'comb_indx': 42300EE, 'country': {6: 'EE', 7: 'EE', 8: ''EE'}, 'type': {6: 'SMALL_LOAN', 7: 'SMALL_LOAN', 8: 'SMALL_LOAN'}}, 
}
```

Basically, group by values in 'comb_indx'.

I've tried all similar questions, but I keep on getting errors.

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question, even if it doesn't work, and describe what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a defaultdict to group the items by the 'comb_indx' value, and then convert the defaultdict back to a list of dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {'comb_indx': {0: '3925220EE', 1: '3925220EE', 2: '3925220EE', 3: '66478EE', 4: '66478EE', 5: '66478EE', 6: '42300EE', 7: '42300EE', 8: '42300EE'}, 'country': {0: 'EE', 1: 'EE', 2: 'EE', 3: 'EE', 4: 'EE', 5: 'EE', 6: 'EE', 7: 'EE', 8: 'EE'}, 'type': {0: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 1: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 2: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 3: 'SMALL_LOAN', 4: 'SMALL_LOAN', 5: 'SMALL_LOAN', 6: 'SMALL_LOAN', 7: 'SMALL_LOAN', 8: 'SMALL_LOAN'}}

# group by 'comb_indx'
grouped = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for i, comb_indx in data['comb_indx'].items():
    for k, v in data.items():
        grouped[comb_indx][k].append(v[i])

# convert defaultdict to list of dicts
result = []
for k, v in grouped.items():
   new_dict = {'comb_indx': k}
   new_dict.update(v)
   result.append(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
[
    {'comb_indx': '3925220EE', 'country': ['EE', 'EE', 'EE'], 'type': ['CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT']},
    {'comb_indx': '66478EE', 'country': ['EE', 'EE', 'EE'], 'type': ['SMALL_LOAN', 'SMALL_LOAN', 'SMALL_LOAN']},
    {'comb_indx': '42300EE', 'country': ['EE', 'EE', 'EE'], 'type': ['SMALL_LOAN', 'SMALL_LOAN', 'SMALL_LOAN']}
]
```

Comment: thank you, that was really fast. When I try your code, I get error with converting defaultdict to list of dicts. The error is the following - TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'comb_indx'.

Comment: Updated the code, now working for your solution

Answer (score 0):

I would use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for this.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display


d = {'comb_indx': {0: '3925220EE', 1: '3925220EE', 2: '3925220EE', 3: '66478EE', 4: '66478EE', 5: '66478EE', 6: '42300EE', 7: '42300EE', 8: '42300EE'}, 'country': {0: 'EE', 1: 'EE', 2: 'EE', 3: 'EE', 4: 'EE', 5: 'EE', 6: 'EE', 7: 'EE', 8: 'EE'}, 'type': {0: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 1: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 2: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 3: 'SMALL_LOAN', 4: 'SMALL_LOAN', 5: 'SMALL_LOAN', 6: 'SMALL_LOAN', 7: 'SMALL_LOAN', 8: 'SMALL_LOAN'}} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

for idx, group in df.groupby('comb_indx'):
    print(idx)
    display(group)
    print(group.to_dict()) #if you want a dict
```

If pandas is not an option, then what about a simple loop?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'comb_indx': {0: '3925220EE', 1: '3925220EE', 2: '3925220EE', 3: '66478EE', 4: '66478EE', 5: '66478EE', 6: '42300EE', 7: '42300EE', 8: '42300EE'}, 'country': {0: 'EE', 1: 'EE', 2: 'EE', 3: 'EE', 4: 'EE', 5: 'EE', 6: 'EE', 7: 'EE', 8: 'EE'}, 'type': {0: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 1: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 2: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 3: 'SMALL_LOAN', 4: 'SMALL_LOAN', 5: 'SMALL_LOAN', 6: 'SMALL_LOAN', 7: 'SMALL_LOAN', 8: 'SMALL_LOAN'}} 
group_by = 'comb_indx'

indexes = set(d[group_by].values()) #unique 'comb_indx'
grouped = []
for i in indexes:
    keys = [k for k,v in d[group_by].items() if v == i] #get keys at index
    group = defaultdict(dict)
    for col in d:
        for k in keys:
            group[col].update({k:d[col][k]})

    grouped.append(dict(group))
        
for _d in grouped:
    print(_d)

{'comb_indx': {3: '66478EE', 4: '66478EE', 5: '66478EE'}, 'country': {3: 'EE', 4: 'EE', 5: 'EE'}, 'type': {3: 'SMALL_LOAN', 4: 'SMALL_LOAN', 5: 'SMALL_LOAN'}}
{'comb_indx': {6: '42300EE', 7: '42300EE', 8: '42300EE'}, 'country': {6: 'EE', 7: 'EE', 8: 'EE'}, 'type': {6: 'SMALL_LOAN', 7: 'SMALL_LOAN', 8: 'SMALL_LOAN'}}
{'comb_indx': {0: '3925220EE', 1: '3925220EE', 2: '3925220EE'}, 'country': {0: 'EE', 1: 'EE', 2: 'EE'}, 'type': {0: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 1: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT', 2: 'CREDIT_ACCOUNT'}}
```

Comment: thank you @alec_djinn - using pandas is not an option, unfortunately. I need to group data while reading sql query in beam pipeline, and dataframes don't work well here. Anyway, thank you very much for your input.